# Xamarin GestureDetector OnFling and ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, swipe, gesture

I'm using Xamarin and I have an Activity that only have a FrameLayout. In the Activity I also have som ActionBar Tabs (created with help from this link:
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/actionbar/ ) that replaces my FrameLayout with Fragments that exists of one small TextView on top and a ListView on the rest of the screen.

Now I want to have the ability to swipe between the Tabs and I found an example from this link: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/create_a_gesture_listener/

The problem is that it only reacts on swipe over the TextView, not the ListView.

In my main Activity I declare

```
private GestureDetector _gestureDetector;
private int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
```

and in OnCreate I have this:

```
_gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
```

And my swipe functions in my main Activity:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
    return false;
}
public bool OnDown(MotionEvent e) { 
    return true; 
}
public bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{
    try {
        if (Math.Abs (e1.GetY () - e2.GetY ()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH) {
            return false;
        }
        // right to left swipe, dvs gå till höger
        if ((e1.GetX () - e2.GetX () > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && (Math.Abs (velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Left Swipe", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        } 
        // left to right swipe, dvs gå till vänster
        else if ((e2.GetX () - e1.GetX () > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) && (Math.Abs (velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Right Swipe", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine (ex.Message);
    }
    return true;
}
public void OnLongPress(MotionEvent e) {}
public bool OnScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    return false;
}
public void OnShowPress(MotionEvent e) {}
public bool OnSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    return false; 
}
```

I searched and searched but only found examples for Java that I don't can convert to C# and Xamarin. What to do? Is there more code you need to see?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a slightly different approach where you use `ViewPager` to support the swiping ability. Just take a look at this [example](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/ActionBarViewPager/) in Xamarin samples, it's a bit buggy but you can get the gist from it.

Comment: The swipe thing worked like a charm but as you said, it's a bit buggy, it crashes while orientation changes for example (missing default constructor for GenericViewPagerFragment) and I can't fix that. And I also don't know how to update my ListViews from the Refresh button in the ActionBar.